# JQuery - Detecting which div box was clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to detect which div box was clicked with JQuery and I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. I'm aware that I can approach this in a different method by directly calling functions if a div box is clicked, but I wish to do it this way by first determining what was clicked.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).click(function(event){
        var id = event.target.id; //looks for the id of what was clicked
        if (id != "myDivBox"){
            callAFunction();
        } else {
            callSomeOtherFunction();
        }
    });
});
```

Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: For starters, I think that you should place the `click` event on `'div'` instead of the entire `document`.

Comment: and what is not working, you could just check if id is set and the rest part of code looks fine - `var id = typeof event.target.id !== 'undefined' ? event.target.id : '' ;`

Comment: Looks fine. Note that if you have something inside the div, and that something is being clicked, target will contain that something rather than the div.

Comment: It wasn't calling the correct functions so I thought I wrote it wrong. Kevin's note made sense and that might be why my functions weren't being called. I will look into that. Thank you!

Comment: The event delegation version of `.on` would make your code work the way you expect.

Comment: If any answers provided here were useful to you, please consider accepting an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `closest` function to get the first ancestor element with tag `div`, see following example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).click(function(event){
      var parentDiv = $(event.target).closest("div");
      console.log(parentDiv.prop("id"));
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1">
  <span id="span1">Test1</span>
</div>
<div id="div2">
  <span id="span2">Test2</span>
</div>
```

I hope it helps you. Bye.

Answer (score 0):

No matter what you click, you will always know the element that was clicked:

```
$("#myDiv").click(function(e){
     alert("I was pressed by " + e.target.id);
});
```

Knowing that you don't want to add this to every div, and you have your click on your document, you'll need to figure out what divs can be reported as "clicked".

In order to do this you'll either need a strict hierarchy of elements in your DOM (which is anoyingly bad) or you can decorate "clickable" div's with a specific class.

Fiddle - similar to below. https://jsfiddle.net/us6968Ld/

I would use closest in Jquery to get the result you want.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).click(function(event){
     var id = event.target.id;
      var clickDiv = $(event.target).closest('div[class="clickable"]');
      alert(clickDiv[0].id);
    
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="clickable" id="clickable1">
<span id="foo"> click me - Foo - clickable 1</span>
</div>
<div id="notClickable1">
  <div class="clickable" id="clickable2">
    <span id="span1">
      Click Me Inside Span 1 - clickable 2
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="clickable" id="clickable3">
    <div id="notClickable2">
      <div id="notClickable3">
        <span id="click me">Click Me - clickable 3</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$('div').click(function() {
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1ct0kv55/1/